# frame to htaccess or php redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i have a domain pointing to my main, but hes using a frame (i cant change this, my host only provides this type of redirect and dont even allow me to redirect to a redirect.html)

```
<FRAME SRC="http://www.domain111.com/" NORESIZE>
```

how can i force this secondary domain to redirect to my main site, without frames?
so far i tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain222.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain222.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain111.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

also

```
if (preg_match("/domain2222.com/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: http://www.domain111.com/");
  exit;
}
```

but thats a infinite loop since the redirect comes from that frame

what should i do? changing host is not a option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible only with a Javascript-based [frame buster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller).

A primitive version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(top != self) top.location.replace("http://maindomain.com");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@thejh: Break out of the `frame`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (top.location != self.location) top.location = self.location;
// -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

after trying for a day I found the solution without javascript!

It uses htaccess only, and I put it in the directory where I point my frame:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.ethicsoft\.it/(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.ethicsoft.it/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

it worked for me, but I suggest to make some test with different combination of browsers and domain providers with frames, because it totally depends on the referer value passed to the framed page.

hoping is helpful!